# Clone a jQuery UI draggable element by clicking a button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable `div` and I want to make a copy of it by clicking a button.

Please watch this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolesterman/cj2f2kd7/1/).

I tried:

```
$('#drag').clone(true).appendTo('body');
```

and

```
$('#drag').clone(true).draggable().appendTo('body');
```

Why isn't the cloned element draggable? And why when I drag the cloned element the original element move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `true` for the first parameter of the `.clone()` method, then all data and events will be copied as the [documentation states](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). Therefore, if you don't the draggable event listeners to be copied, you should omit the first parameter (since it will default to `false`):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/fetzfyck/)

```
$('.drag').draggable();

$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('.drag:first').clone().draggable().appendTo('body');
});
```

```js
$('.drag').draggable();

$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('.drag:first').clone().draggable().appendTo('body');
});
```

```css
.drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">duplicate</button>
<div class='drag'></div>
```

---

Alternatively, if you need to retain the element's data and events, then you could temporarily remove the element's draggable functionality before cloning it by calling the `destroy` option. From there, you can re-initialize the draggable functionality once the cloned element has been appended to the document:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLope20u/)

```
$('.drag').draggable();

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.drag:first').draggable("destroy").clone(true).appendTo('body');

  $('.drag').draggable();
});
```

As a side note, an `id` is suppose to be unique within a document. Therefore I used a class instead in the example above.

```js
$('.drag').draggable();

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.drag:first').draggable("destroy").clone(true).appendTo('body');

  $('.drag').draggable();
});
```

```css
.drag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="drag"></div>

<button id="btn">duplicate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh, it works great, a simple question though: So there is no other way, without removing draggable?

Comment: @cool - I updated the answer... You could omit the first parameter in the `clone()` method (when `true` is specified, the element's events/data are cloned as well, which is why the draggable functionality was copied over). I am not sure if that is helpful, though, since you probably want the events to be copied over.

Comment: The first answer was awesome but the Updated Example (the short one) is just what I need, I'm gonna say "now you're talking" , thank you so much @Josh.